# Python list remove another list with unknown variable

Tags: python, list, python-2.6

I am using version 2.6 of python its list functionality.

I was wondering if there is any faster way to get the wanted result, rather than iterating over all of its items.
The issue that I'm having is with the inner list, that contains a dynamic (unknown) variable. I want to delete the one that matches my manually input list.

```
lst = [[5, 222, 5],[6, 0, 2]]

if [6, 0, _] in lst: 
   lst.remove([6, 0, _]);
```

The upper code doesn't seem to work. I am looking for more elegant and a working solution.

Comment: _ is undefined in that code. _ is not a placeholder you can use to indicate any value.

Comment: Any specific criteria for deleting element ? For that you can use filter over list.

Comment: can you explain better what are you trying to do?? give an example? what is `_`?

Comment: `_` for *I'll ignore this* names is a *convention*, not actual syntax. You cannot use it as a wildcard like that.

Comment: The third variable is the one i don't care about, it can be -50 or 555, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a more generic way:

```
lst = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,4],
    [1,2,6],
    [2,5,4],
    [2,5,5],
    [3,7,9],
]

search = [1, None, 6]
new = [a for a in lst if
    any(y is not None and x != y for x, y in zip(a, search))
]

print new
```

where `None` is a placeholder

Comment: Nicely done, but note that for `search = [6, 0, None]` your code would remove `[6, 0]`

Comment: @Korem: of course, this code only makes sense if all lists are of the same length.

Answer (score 8):

This is almost certainly a bad idea, but I thought it would be fun to make your original code work the way you want. We just have to make `_` be a value that compares equal to anything and everything.

```
class OmniMatcher:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

_ = OmniMatcher()

lis = [[5, 222, 5],[6, 0, 2]]
if [6, 0, _] in lis: 
   lis.remove([6, 0, _]);

print(lis)
```

Result:

```
[[5, 222, 5]]
```

the [6,0,2] element is removed, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: lis = [[5, 222, 5],[6, 0, 2]]

In [2]: [x for x in lis if len(x) != 3 or x[0] != 6 and x[1] != 0]
Out[2]: [[5, 222, 5]]
```

The condition executes from left to right. So we first check the length of each components - and let lists with length different than three pass our filter. If the length is 3, we filter out lists whose first item is 6 and second 3, not minding the third item.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have `[6, 0, '_']` on your list so you can remove it with following code:

```
lis = [[5, 222, 5],[6, 0, 2],[6, 0, '_']]

print [item for item in lis if any(x not in [6, 0, '_'] for x in item)]
```

result:

```
[[5, 222, 5], [6, 0, 2]]
```

**if not** , and you have not [6, 0, _] in your list you should just change the `any` abuilt in function to `all` :

```
lis = [[5, 222, 5],[6, 0, 2],[6, 0, '_']]

print [item for item in lis if all(x not in [6, 0, '_'] for x in item)]
```

result:

```
[[5, 222, 5]]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you always know the value of the first and second items of the inner list you can use list comprehensions.

```
l = [i for i in lis if i[0] != 6 and i[1] != 0]
```

or

```
l = [i for i in lis if i[:2] != [6, 0]]
```

The code is cleaner and more pythonic that way. Performance-wise I don't think there'll be much difference.

Comment: Original question wishes to remove the items from the list that start with [6, 0] not extract them. Might want to switch it to a `!=`

Comment: Your code would fail both on [6,0,5,3] and is doing the opposite of what the OP wanted (filtering in and not out). It would also raise an exception on [3]